# How to create an uncle node (= brother of parent)

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have types set up in a way that it does not allow to create a node under a certain type of node. This works out of the box. But I would like to change it that if a user tries it, it just creates it above the node, so as an uncle.

Example:

```
Parent 1
Parent 2
-- child 1
-- child 2
Parent 3
```

So if a user clicks on child 2 and wants to create a new node, it should just put it one hierarchy highers, becoming Parent 4.
My code right now of the button is this:

```
case "add_folder":
     $("#demo").jstree("create", null, "first", 
                       { "attr" : 
                           { "rel" : this.id.toString().replace("add_", "") } 
                       });
 break;
```

I have already checked that the second parameter in the list is for the position of the new node ("first" in the above code). But as far as I can see it allows only the following:

- before
- after
- inside
- first
- last

But what I need is something like `above`.

Do you guys have any idea how to work around this?

Comment: Where is the node created if you use 'last'?

Comment: Last would put it after the last child, so after Child2 in the case above

Answer (score 2):

in jQuery there is a [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)() function which works nice with [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)().